# Running same code in different conditions in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to reduce/simplify the following code as it looks to have repeated elements:

```
<?php
if ($condition == true) {
  if ($a > $b*0.5) {
    echo "successful";
  }
  else {
    echo "missed";
  }
}
else {
  if ($a > $b) {
    echo "successful";
  } 
  else {
    echo "missed";
  }
}
```

I don't want to use functions because if I did, I would have to define all the database things again.

Comment: How do functions and database come into this? Are you using a framework or something?

Comment: Data comes from mysql with pdo.

Comment: I still don't see why you could not pass it as parameter to a function

Comment: Because of a point I don't understand about functions and it's still complicated for me. That's why I don't want to mess with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
if ( (condition1 && ($a > $b*0.5)) || (!condition1 && ($a > $b))  ) {
  echo "successful"; 
else {
  echo "missed";
}
?>
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks

Comment: And not a sign of a PDO database in sight :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is missed Two (Semicoloumns)`}`.
Try By this

```
<?php

$a == 2;
$b == 4;

if ($a == 2 && $a > $b*0.5) {
    echo "Suuccess";
}elseif($a != 2 && $a > $b){
    echo "Suuccess";
}else{
    echo "Fails";
}
```

Comment: Welcome @E.Henry

Answer (score 0):

In order to simplify your conditions, if the output is `boolean` (so only two outcomes possible) you could go with either one as default and only change it to the other depending on your decisions.

```
<?php
$outcome = false;
if($condition1 && ($a > ($b * 0.5))) {
  $outcome = true;
}
else if($a > $b) {
  $outcome = true;
}

if($outcome) {
  echo "succesful";
}
else {
  echo "missed";
}
```

This also combines the technique proposed by [Sofyan Thayf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48618342/7926064) to use [boolean operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) to merge conditions.

Another approach is to put the condition into a function and return early if `succesful` and have a `missed` fallthrough like

```
<?php
function decide($a, $b, $condition1) {
  if($condition1 && ($a > ($b * 0.5)))
    return true;
  if($a > $b)
    return true;

  return false;
}

if(decide($a, $b, $condition1)) {
  echo "succesful";
}
else {
  echo "missed";
}
```

Both approaches enable you to extract the "same code" (being the `echo`) and IMHO add to readability and extensibility.

Comment: A different perspective. I'll try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$factor = $condition ? 0.5 : 1;

if ($a > $b * $factor) {
    echo "Hit";
} 
else {
    echo "Miss";
}
```

Could be further reduced using two ternary operators:

```
echo $a > $b * ($condition ? 0.5 : 1)
    ? 'Hit'
    : 'Miss';
```

Ternary operators are useful shorthand for if/else conditionals.